# Android image effect

Tags: android, image-processing

if i capture any image from android camera ,, how can i perform different -2 type of effect on image? Effect should be like "sepia", "Old cam" etc... These effect must be perform after capturing the image...

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851629/how-to-apply-effects-to-camera-images)

Comment: Didn't you just ask this the other day and accept an answer for it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851629/how-to-apply-effects-to-camera-images

Comment: This question is little bit of different coz here i have to apply effect after capturing the photo...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Android does not offer dedicated classes for this. You can do that either:

- in Java code, use android.graphics.Bitmap and accompanied classes for color filtering, blur, emboss and xfer mode.
- use NDK. Actual image processing is done in C++ (maybe you already have some libraries for this), only final result is delivered to Android for display