# image Effect android using GPUImage

Tags: android-library, gpuimage, glsurfaceview, imagefilter, image-effects

I am not even aware of Image Effects, I am trying to use Image filter to one image on which i have done with Drawing. For Drawing i have used DrawingView but now for effect i googled it and i have came to know that it can b apply using GLSurfaceView, ImageView, etc but i dont know

**[FIRST QUESTION]**

it can be apply to DrawingView?

Now i have tried GPUImage i found some code from github but not worked for me because i dont even know how i works

**[SECOND QUESTION]**

Steps to use GPUImage for image effects?

i have reffered this examples:

https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/ 
(this is not using GPUImage but somehow main goal is image effect)

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgpuimagelibrary110sourcesjar.htm 
(Download Library from Here - ver- 1.1.1)

http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2013/10/apply-effects-on-image-using-effects.html 
(Nothing happning to image when clicking menu)

https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage (What is that i did not understand: code? then why Library folder is there?)

**already asked questions but not worked**

[How to apply effects to camera images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851629/how-to-apply-effects-to-camera-images)
(Complex for me)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html
(Theory)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592646/display-grayscale-to-color-image-when-state-change-using-gpuimage-in-android

[How to add image effects in android ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043533/how-to-add-image-effects-in-android)

and many more available but i dont know how to do that.. Anybody can suggest something better.. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. First question: You should try again and run GPU lib follow link https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage. It should work if you config project properly
2. Second question: Don't use other libraries for Image effects, because it is written by Java code, you will face with Out of memory problem, take time for each effect by Java code also, it is really annoy. GPU lib is written by C++ and it is really cool to apply for Image editor apps

Hope you run GPU sample successfully

Comment: hey i have reffered this link :  https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage.  it includes two main folders one is sample(App) and other is Library - how to get this folder? i have import GPUImage library in this but still not working.

Comment: You know, I just download from that link, import into Android Studio as Project, it compiles and work well. You should try again. My current Android Studio version is 1.4. Which problem did you face? Please list down

Comment: Error:`Gradle 2.4 requires Android Gradle plugin 1.2.0 (or newer)  but project is using version 1.0.0.
Please use Android Gradle plugin 1.2.0 or newer.
<a href="fixGradleElements">Fix plugin version and sync project</a> `                THIS ERROR M FACING, MY ANDROID STUDIO VERSION IS 1.4

Comment: AND WHEN I RUN THE APP : `Error:Execution failed for task ':library:compileReleaseAidl'.
> Executor Singleton not started`

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
compileSdkVersion 23, 
buildToolsVersion 23.0.1, 
gradle 2.4, 
Please update  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3' in Gradle file

Comment: Error:(14, 0) Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.
<a href="openFile:E:\PROJECT\android-gpuimage-master\library\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage is easy to deploy with dependency only

Comment: I am using the library but unable to refresh the image. How do I change the bitmap any idea?